# Verify whether this is a group or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G = a_0,a_1, \cdots, a_6$ where $a_i\cdot a_j = a_{i+j}$ if $i+j <
>  7$ and $a_i\cdot a_j = a_{i+j-7}$ if $i+j \ge 7$.

I'm trying to see whether this is a group or not. The problem is I can't see what the identity element or the inverses would be from the definition. I tried to prove closure and associativity:

(a) By definition for any $a_i, a_j \in G$ we have $a_i\cdot a_j = a_{i+j} \in G$ if $i+j <7$ and $a_i\cdot a_j = a_{i+j-7} \in G$ if $i+j \ge 7$.

(b) For any $a_i, a_j, c_k \in G$ we have $$a_i \cdot (a_j \cdot a_k)=\begin{cases}
 a_i \cdot a_{j+k} = a_{i+j+k} & \mbox{if } i+j+k < 7 \\
   a_i \cdot a_{j+k-7} = a_{i+j+k-14} & \mbox{if } j+k \ge  7 \\ a_i\cdot a_{j+k} = a_{i+j+k-7} & \mbox{if}  ~i+j+k \ge 7, j+k < 7 
\end{cases}$$

And similarly we have $$(a_i \cdot a_j) \cdot a_k=\begin{cases}
 a_{i+j} \cdot a_{k} = a_{i+j+k} & \mbox{if } i+j+k < 7 \\
   a_{i+j-7} \cdot a_{k} = a_{i+j+k-14} & \mbox{if } i+j \ge  7 \\ a_{i+j}\cdot a_{k} = a_{i+j+k-7} & \mbox{if}  ~i+j+k \ge 7,  i+j < 7
\end{cases}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Identity $e = a_x$ such that $a_x*a_i = a_{x + i} = a_i$ if $x + i < 7$ and $a_x*a_i = a_{x+i -7} = a_i$.  So what can $x$ be equal to?

Comment: @fleablood $x = 0$, so that the identity element is $a_0$?

Comment: Well, that'd sure make sense, wouldn't it?  $a_0*a_i = a_{0+i} = a_i = a_i*a_0$.  That seems .... pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: @fleablood it does indeed, thanks. What would the inverse be, though? $a_{x}a_{i} = a_{x+i} = a_0$, so $a_{-i}$? This sounds wrong, however.

Comment: @Frentos I'm totally confused now. Are these the same? Because I understand the other problem. Not this one, however.

Comment: @user276387: It's equivalent. The other problem stated that $a^0=a^n=e$. That was redundant of Herstein: you get $a^0$ as the identity from his definition of multiplication.

Comment: $(a_i)^{-1} = a_{-i}$ sounds wrong?  Why?  Well, I guess because we don't have any $a_{-i}$.  So you'll have to use $a_{7 - i}$.  Try it.  It'll work.  It will turn out that this is equivalent to a cyclic group.  $a_n = a_1 + a_1 + ....$ n times.  The notation looks different, but they are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, the only difference is that the notation of one was $a^i$ and the notation of the other was $a_i$.  Now $a^i$ gives the impression that we are doing multiplication and $a_i$ gives the impression that we simply are defining indexes and can't make any assumptions.  But that's misleading.  These are purely abstract groups so the definition $a_i*a_n = a_{i + n}$ while defining $a^i \cdot a^n = a^{i + n}$ is ... exactly the same, isn't it?

Comment: @fleablood, I understand now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is exercise 1(c) Section 3, Chapter 2 from Herstein's "Topics in Algebra".

Here Herstein is simply being sadistic with his definitions. If you know about modulo arithmetic, your brain is screaming "$a_j = a_k$ iff $j \equiv k \pmod{7}$". Instead, we have to flounder with 6 special cases regarding the ranges of $i+j$, $j+k$ and $i+j+k$ to show transitivity.  While what you've written for (b) so far is correct, it's incomplete: it doesn't directly tie the two expressions together.

Modulo arithmetic can't be used directly in this exercise, and expecting a beginning student to be able to make a bijection between $G$ and the equivalences classes of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ and prove its correctness seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Thank you! I skipped the section on integers, so I don't know modular arithmetic. I guess I'm gonna have to have to go back to that section.